# ¿Como editar líneas de un DataFrame CSV en Python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data

### **Hola a Todos!**

Yo tengo un archivo **.CSV** transformado a **DataFrame** que contiene más de **4000** Filas y **7** Columnas. En mi programa, el Usuario podrá ingresar Datos, Buscarlos, Eliminarlos y demás. Pero, me gustaría poder crear una opción para que pueda **modificar** un dato en específico, de una columna y fila en específico.

**Archivo CSV (Resumido):**

```
 ,Fila,Grabados,Cilindros,Almacenamiento,Estado,Fecha
 ,1,10005,1,T53,GRABADO,01/11/2017
 ,2,10015,1,Q06,DESGRABADO,01/11/2017
```

Por ejemplo: El usuario quiere modificar el nombre del Grabado **10015**. Entonces, el programa pide un nuevo nombre (Supongamos **10020**), busca el grabado y cambia su nombre sin afectar al resto del archivo. Esto dejándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
 ,Fila,Grabados,Cilindros,Almacenamiento,Estado,Fecha
 ,1,10005,1,T53,GRABADO,01/11/2017
 ,2,10020,1,Q06,DESGRABADO,01/11/2017
```

He intentado de muchas formas pero no doy con la solución.
Uno de mis intentos fue...

```
def Editar(Filas, Columna, Escribir):
 Contenido = list()
 Archivo = "Data_Base.csv"
 with open(Archivo, 'r+') as archivo:
    Contenido = archivo.readlines()
    for Fila in Filas:
        Columnas = Contenido[Fila-1].split(',')
        Columnas[Columna] = Escribir
        Contenido[Fila-1] = ','.join(Columnas)+ '\n'
 with open(Archivo, 'w') as archivo:
    archivo.writelines(Contenido)
```

Pero tengo que ingresar la columna (Que no me afecta) y la Fila (Lo que realmente me afecta)

**Muchas gracias!**

Comment: No solo digas lo que has intentado, muestralo!!!

Comment: @eyllanesc Listo! Editado con mi intento más cercano!

Comment: Puedes usar o bien Pandas cargando los datos en un DataFrame o bien `csv.DictReader` para poder buscar la fila en la que el valor de la columna `Grabados` sea el que quieras y modificarla adecuadamente. Teniendo en cuenta tu pregunta anterior, la eficiencia de esto es discutible porque un csv es una de las peores opciones si se desean hacer alteraciones en la tabla que no sean agregar filas al principio o al final del archivo. En una base de datos esta operación es trivial, en un csv por lo general implica cargar en memoria y sobrescribir el archivo al completo y con muchos datos esto es...

Comment: @FJSevilla Ok! Qué me recomiendas para reemplazar los archivos CSV? Escuché de JSON pero soy Novato en esto ;)

Comment: JSON es otra mala idea, si vas a modificar o altera valores continuamente te recomienda usar una base de datos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Lo voy a tener en cuenta!!!

Comment: Como comenta eyllanesc un JSON no deja de ser prácticamente lo mismo (un simple archivo que hay que parsear, cargar en memoria y reescribir). Una base de datos te da mucha más flexibilidad, escalabilidad y eficiencia. Puedes empezar con [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) (incluida en la biblioteca estándar de Python). [Pytables](http://www.pytables.org/)(basada en HDF5) puede ser también una opción. En cualquiera de los dos casos puedes trabajar con Pandas si lo necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando pandas es la forma más sencilla, para ello primero usamos la funcion loc para localizar el elemento, despues lo reemplazamos y al final lo guardamos:

```
import pandas as pd
filename = "Data_Base.csv"
valin = 10015
valout =  10020

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
try:
    df.loc[df['Grabados'] == valin, "Grabados"] = valout
    df.to_csv(filename)
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: Gracias! Lo voy a probar!

Comment: Te recomiendo que aparte de probarla, la entiendas. Para ello debes entender cada funcion.

Comment: Si! Es lo que estaba viendo! No me gusta copiar y pegar :D. Por el momento, estoy entendiendo cada función y sacando mis conclusiones.